# how to select records for today only with custom date settings

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a db and below is the date input format.

```
$date = date('m.d.Y');
```

I want to display all the records by one user for today only.

I am using the query below to extract records, but it's not working for me.

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) AS total FROM tablename where userid='$userid' 
 and  date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Kindly suggest solution.

Comment: Did you mean `and  $date`? Also, MySQL runs from `YYYY-MM-DD` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- ,, yes ---- and date BETWEEN ------

Comment: If that is your actual code, `date` is missing `$`. Try it again and see, while changing your `m.d.Y` to `Y-m-d`

Comment: @Fred-ii- ,, date is column name from where i am extracting data

Comment: How is it not working? Your interval is not only the current day, its the past 24 hours. Is that problem?

Comment: To narrow it down make sure that the first part works `SELECT COUNT(userid) AS total FROM tablename where userid='$userid'` I have used php a long time ago - are you sure that userid is passed the right way? Is userid a string or an int?

Comment: THE FORMAT FOR date IS text ... I cant change the table for reasons. need to extract data from 1 day only. YES, the problem is its not displaing data for past 24 hrs.

Comment: Why in the Lord's name are you storing dates as text? Now you've got your work cut out for you.

Comment: If your column `date` is of type `TEXT` you may want to look at [can-mysql-filter-by-date-if-date-is-stored-as-text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563022/)

Answer (score 0):

Your interval is a full 24 hours, but it sounds like you only want the current day. Also `$userid` is probably an integer, if that is the case you should remove the quotes Your `WHERE` clause should look like the following:

`WHERE userid = $userid AND date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND NOW()`.

**In response to your comment**

If you are storing your dates a string (wierd) the following might work better:

`WHERE date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m.%d.%Y')`

<s>I can't test that readily, you may need to tweak it.</s> That should do it.

Comment: Have you read OP's last comment? *"THE FORMAT FOR date IS text ... I cant change the table for reasons. need to extract data from 1 day only. YES, the problem is its not displaing data for past 24 hrs."* - Keyword here is "text". Ouch

Comment: @dan08, i have shown u  the date format, but cant get any clues how can i fetch enteries for past 24hrs fmr this format. if you are kind enough to give me any clues how to fetch the data from the current format. that will be more help full for me.

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted only the same date. If you don't have data about which hour the record was made, I don't see a good way to filter by hours, you just don't have that information.